# Hi, How to update negative values as Zero in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

CASE
WHEN round(months_between(CURRENT_DATE, nvl(bpi.StartDate, cli.StartDate))) > round(months_between(nvl(bpi.EndDate, cli.EndDate), nvl(bpi.StartDate, cli.StartDate)))
THEN round(months_between(nvl(bpi.EndDate, cli.EndDate), nvl(bpi.StartDate, cli.StartDate)))
ELSE round(months_between(CURRENT_DATE, nvl(bpi.StartDate, cli.StartDate)), 1)
END AS Months_Used

Answer (score 1):

Using update:

```
UPDATE tab
SET col = 0
WHERE col < 0;
```

Alternatively without actual change in base table using `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col < 0 THEN 0 ELSE col END AS col
FROM tab;
```